# Dynamically checkboxes, radio, checkboxgroups, radiogroups extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

Hi Dear stackoverflow guys!

I searched about this issue in stackowerflow but none of them is helpfull for me

```
my model is like that:
Ext.define('soru', {
        extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields : [{
                name : 'CEVAP',
                type : 'string'
                },
                {
                name : 'VALUE',
                type : 'int'
                },
                {
                name : 'RECNO',
                type : 'int'
                }
        ]
    });
```

And my store is like :

```
checkboxArray = [];  
var myStoresoru = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model : 'soru',
        id:'sorustore',
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'fetchsoru.php',
            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                root : 'data'
            }
        },
        listeners: {                                                                                                                          
                load: function(value, records, options) {                                                                                               
                    for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) { 
                           console.log(records);  
                           console.log(records.length);                                                                                
                      checkboxArray.push(new Ext.form.Checkbox(
                                    { 
                                        boxLabel: value.data.items[i].data.CEVAP,
                                        name: value.data.keys[i],
                                        xtype: 'checkbox',
                                        inputValue: value.data.items[i].data.VALUE,
                                        id: value.data.items[i].data.RECNO
                                    }));
                      //{id: records[i].data.id, boxLabel: records[i].data.pagetitle});                                              
                    }                                                                                                                               
                }  
            }, 

        autoLoad : false
    });                                                                                                                                   
myStoresoru.load();
```

my checkboxgroup is like:

```
var check= new Ext.form.CheckboxGroup({  
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',//combo çoklu seçim olmalı
                fieldLabel: 'İklimsa’yı tercih nedeniniz? ',
                //store: myStoresoru,
                labelWidth:300,
                //columns:2,
                name : 'tercih',
                id : 'tercih',
                itemId: 'tercih',
                hiddenName: 'tercih',
                items:[checkboxArray]
```

});

and form :

```
form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', { items : [check]
    });
```

Well my question is that  checkboxes is not load to checkboxgroup in. when i type checckboxArray on console i can see that checckboxArray exist but i dont know why checckboxes is not shown

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for replaying me. I have already solved and i want to share my solution to help someone  who search for dynamic checkbox and chexbox group in extjs

in my store i wrote my checkboxgroup and radiogroup

```
var myStoresoru = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model : 'soru',
        id:'sorustore',
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'fetchsoru.php',
            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                root : 'data'
            }
        },
        listeners: {                                                                                                                          
                load: function(value, records, options) {  

                     for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) { 

                           //console.log(records);  
                           //console.log(records.length); 
                        if(value.data.items[i].data.GROUPID==0)
                            {

                                checkboxGroupArray.push(new Ext.form.CheckboxGroup(
                                { 
                                    fieldLabel: value.data.items[i].data.SORU,
                                    labelWidth:300,
                                    border: '10 5 3 10',
                                    bodyPadding: 10,
                                    columns:2,
                                    id: value.data.items[i].data.RECNOSORU,
                                    xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                                    originalValue:value.data.items[i].data.SORUTIPI
                                    //layout: 
                                }));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                radioGroupArray.push(new Ext.form.RadioGroup(
                                { 
                                    fieldLabel: value.data.items[i].data.SORU,
                                    border: '10 5 3 10',
                                    bodyPadding: 10,
                                    labelWidth:300,
                                    columns:2,
                                    id: value.data.items[i].data.RECNOSORU,
                                    xtype: 'radiogroup',
                                    originalValue:value.data.items[i].data.SORUTIPI
                                }));
                            }


                    } }  
            }, 

        autoLoad : false
    });
```

And load them in form after loading checboxes and radiofields inside to their gruop items

```
var myStorecevap = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model : 'cevap',
        id:'cevapstore',
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'fetchcevap.php',
            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                root : 'data'
            }
        },
        listeners: {                                                                                                                          
                load: function(value, records, options) {  

                     for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) { 

                           //console.log(records);  
                           //console.log(records.length); 
                           if(value.data.items[i].data.GROUPID==0)
                            {
                                checkboxArray.push(new Ext.form.Checkbox(
                                { 
                                    boxLabel: value.data.items[i].data.CEVAP,
                                    name: value.data.keys[i],
                                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                                    labelWidth:300,
                                    columns:2,
                                    inputValue: value.data.items[i].data.VALUE,
                                    id: value.data.items[i].data.RECNO,
                                    stateId:value.data.items[i].data.SORUTIPI
                                }));

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                radioArray.push(new Ext.form.Radio(
                                { 
                                    boxLabel: value.data.items[i].data.CEVAP,
                                    name: value.data.items[i].data.RECNOSORU,
                                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                                    labelWidth:300,
                                    columns:2,
                                    inputValue: value.data.items[i].data.VALUE,
                                   // id: value.data.items[i].data.RECNOS,
                                  // stateId:value.data.items[i].data.SORUTIPI


                                }));

                            }


                        //console.log(checkboxGroupArray);

                    }
                    //var totalcount=checkboxArray.length+radioGroupArray.length;

                    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) 
                        {
                            for(var j = 0; j < checkboxGroupArray.length; j++) 
                            {
                                console.log(value.data.items[i].data.RECNOSORU);
                                var den=value.data.items[i].data.RECNOSORU;
                                if(checkboxGroupArray[j].id==den) 
                                {
                                    checkboxGroupArray[j].add(checkboxArray[i]);
                                    console.log(checkboxGroupArray);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    Ext.getCmp('forms').add(checkboxGroupArray);

                    for(var k = 0; k < radioArray.length; k++) 
                        {
                            for(var m = 0; m < radioGroupArray.length; m++) 
                            {
                                //console.log(value.data.items[k].data.RECNOSORU);
                                var denm=radioArray[k].name;
                                console.log(radioArray[k].name);
                                //console.log(radioGroupArray[m].id);
                                if(radioGroupArray[m].id==denm) 
                                {
                                    radioGroupArray[m].add(radioArray[k]);
                                    console.log(radioGroupArray[m]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    Ext.getCmp('forms').add(radioGroupArray);
                    arraytext.push(new Ext.form.TextArea(
                                {
                                    xtype     : 'textareafield',
                                    grow      : true,
                                    labelWidth:300,
                                    autoScroll   :    true,
                                    name      : 'message',
                                    id: 'message',
                                    fieldLabel: 'İlave Görüş ve Notlarınız',
                                    anchor    : '100%'
                                    }));


                    Ext.getCmp('forms').add(arraytext);



                }  
            }, 

        autoLoad : false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you add the checkboxArray to the checkboxGroup the array is empty. When the ajax request to load the store finishes and the array is filled, the items in the checkboxGroup are not updated.

The solution is to add the checkboxArray to the checkboxGroup after filling it:

```
...
  load: function(value, records, options) {                                                                                               
    for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) { 
      console.log(records);  
      console.log(records.length);                                                                                
      checkboxArray.push(new Ext.form.Checkbox(
        { 
            boxLabel: value.data.items[i].data.CEVAP,
            name: value.data.keys[i],
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            inputValue: value.data.items[i].data.VALUE,
            id: value.data.items[i].data.RECNO
        }));

      check.add(checkboxArray);

      //{id: records[i].data.id, boxLabel: records[i].data.pagetitle});                                              
   }
```

And also, the way you should have added the array to the checkbox group is:

```
items: checkboxArray
```

because it's already an array on it's own. That line is not necessary anymore though.